# DIVs are not obeying CSS rules. Any ideas?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get this layout in the picture but looks like the DIV tags are not obeying the CSS rules.
I think the issue is because I'm trying to set them in percentage. I need this layout to follow screen size. I don't want any scroller showing. Also if I turn the monitor sideways, it will still obey the layout.

```css
#one {
  height: 20%;
  width: 45%;
  background-color: #66F;
  float: left;
}

#two {
  background-color: #FC3;
  height: 40%;
  width: 45%;
  float: right;
}

#three {
  background-color: #0CC;
  float: left;
  height: 20%;
  width: 45%;
}

#four {
  background-color: #CF3;
  height: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

#five {
  background-color: #F06;
  float: left;
  height: 40%;
  width: 45%;
}

#six {
  background-color: #9C0;
  float: right;
  height: 20%;
  width: 45%;
}

#seven {
  background-color: #3FF;
  float: right;
  height: 20%;
  width: 45%;
}

#eight {
  background-color: #396;
  height: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="one">one</div>
  <div id="two">two</div>
  <div id="three">three</div>
  <div id="four">four</div>
  <br>
  <div id="five">five</div>
  <div id="six">Six</div>
  <div id="seven">Seven</div>
  <div id="eight">Content for id "eight" Goes Here</div>
</body>
```

Any help?

[Layout Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM4c8.jpg)

Comment: I don't wont make this for you. I think you want learn how to do it. My suggest is think this layout first for rows, wrap the sections in 4 div, your rows, and set the rows to width 100%... try and go on.

Comment: Height in percent means a percentage of the height of the parent, at least, if the parent has its height specified. So, if you want a percentage of the screen height, you will need to add `html, body {height:100%}`. That's all.

Answer (score 2):

Percentage width/height is relative to the *nearest positioned ancestor*.
If you want to size your elements relative to the screen size, you can use viewport width/height instead:

```
height: 20vh;
width: 40vw;
```

would be 20% of the viewport height, 40% of the viewport width.

Comment: Not sure how changing percentages to vw/vh could do that. I just tried it in a pen and it seems fine - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ommjmz. On an unrelated note, I'd avoid using `float` if possible as it takes the element out of the flow of the document. A better solution might be to add an empty flex element between your left and right element.

Comment: I tried it too and it works in chrome Version 49.0.2623.112 m; see https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XRReQz.

Answer (score 1):

If you use percentages for height, you have to define heights for all parent element either up to one that has a fixed height or up to `body` and `html`, which typically would be `height: 100%;`:

(In your example there are no other parent elements between your DIVs and `body`, so that one rule should be sufficient)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#one {
  height: 20%;
  width: 45%;
  background-color: #66F;
  float: left;
}

#two {
  background-color: #FC3;
  height: 40%;
  width: 45%;
  float: right;
}

#three {
  background-color: #0CC;
  float: left;
  height: 20%;
  width: 45%;
}

#four {
  background-color: #CF3;
  height: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

#five {
  background-color: #F06;
  float: left;
  height: 40%;
  width: 45%;
}

#six {
  background-color: #9C0;
  float: right;
  height: 20%;
  width: 45%;
}

#seven {
  background-color: #3FF;
  float: right;
  height: 20%;
  width: 45%;
}

#eight {
  background-color: #396;
  height: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">one</div>
<div id="two">two</div>
<div id="three">three</div>
<div id="four">four</div>
</br>
<div id="five">five</div>
<div id="six">Six</div>
<div id="seven">Seven</div>
<div id="eight">Content for id "eight" Goes Here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add this to your CSS:

```
div {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

This will hide all scrollbars.  However, this alone is insufficient because the body,html width and height styles could pose a problem (see [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zwwPzL)). The solution is to add something similar to this in the CSS:

```
html,body {
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

See [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WjjXZj)

Using the CSS vh and vw units is also another way to hide the scrollbars as Ash mentions (see below).  The only drawback is that if the user resizes the browser's window to a smaller size, the scrollbars may appear (try it  [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WjjXxo)).

I did find a way to use the CSS vh and vw measurement units and keep the scrollbars completely hidden as long as the code specifies that the overflow for the html and body are hidden; See [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EmmbZp)